# NHibernate - How to Iterate Persistent Entities Attached to a Session?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a need to inspect the set of attached entities that would be persisted if I called Flush() on a given session.  (I'm writing code that accesses a Session as part of a generic pipeline before saving and it can be used in any number of contexts.)

I find myself wishing that there were a method like

mySession.GetPersistentEntities()

so I could inspect them and perform some preprocessing.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 4):

No, NHibernate's ISession does not expose anything like that. You can either:

- Track these instances yourself (not recommended)
- Use standard NHibernate mechanisms:

  - Event listeners (e.g. IFlushEventListener, ISaveOrUpdateEventListener)
  - Interceptors (IInterceptor.OnFlushDirty(), OnSave())

Answer (score 2):

You could "hack" a little bit into the session context:

```
ISession session;
var sessionContext = session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext;

foreach(var entity in sessionContext.EntitiesByKey.Values)
{
  // do anything with the entity
}
```

However, in your case I would use flush event listeners or an interceptor.